# Why bootstrap col content won't grow width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am missing something really simple. The reason i met this situation is much more complicated, but i simplified it. Consider following simple template with bootstrap classes:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="text">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
         Quo quia fugiat labore atque. Voluptate accusamus quod qui voluptatem nisi nulla.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
}

.text {
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

[class^='col'] {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/rNyQqbP?editors=1100)

**Why won't .col-6 with text grow to a width of at least 250px wide as css rule told it to ?**

**How to make it stretch ?**

**UPDATE::**
To summarize: just long text enlarges .text element that enlarge .col-6 respectively. And explicit width: 250px enlarge .text element but wont enlarge .col-6. In "250px width case" it will be cut off by max-width: 50% property on col-6. But why oO

Comment: yes, i know. but how then width of container (in my case of .row) is calculated ? Based on what ? I thought based on content (which width is set to 250px)

Comment: if you replace long text with short text (removing width property) you will see that column size changes depending on its content, that means that column size does depend on its content. But when setting fixed width for column it breaks for some simple obvious reason that i am missing

Comment: Yes, i know. But why wont .col grow to 250px ? As it does with long text for example. Dont answer because its size of its parent....etc.. we already have found that col does depend on its content size (try replacing .text with short or long text)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is something like in snippet below, then it is working properly.
`.col-6` has declared `width: 50%; flex: 0 0 auto;`. The important part is `0 0` in `flex:` property. What it does is simply prevent element from growing (first `0`) and shrinking (second `0`) so it will maintain `50%` width doesn't without taking into account its content. [Here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flex) you can check what it does more in-depth.

p.s.
I'm assuming that you are using bootstrap 5
In bootstrap 4 `.col-6` has `max-width: 50%;flex: 0 0 50%` which works similarly and will generate same behaviour

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.text {
  width: 250px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

[class^='col'] {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Quo quia fugiat labore atque. Voluptate accusamus quod qui voluptatem nisi nulla.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty for comment. I am aware of flexbox grow and shrink properties. If you add more or less text in .text div you will see .col-6 changing its width based on content. Why can't it change its size to 250px when width is set explicitly ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your environment then. When I add more text and remove `width: 250px` from `.text` then `.text` shinks to fit `.col-6` Even with `width: 250px`, `.text` have same width doesn't matter volume of text.

Comment: if you add like lorem50 you will see that .col-6 will grow in its width, right ? Why then it wont enlarge when width: 250px is set ( as you can see when running code from your answer, it will overlap, overlow .col-6 div ) ?

Comment: So. I have added a buch of paragraphs to `.text` (50 to be exact) like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/GmFFFGRD/Zrzut-ekranu-2021-06-14-o-15-07-53.png) and removed `width: 250px`. Result is as I mentioned above. [Result](https://i.postimg.cc/T3JkRZpB/Zrzut-ekranu-2021-06-14-o-15-08-04.png)

Comment: have you removed width property ? This is what i get : [Result](https://i.imgur.com/aa9Bv2u.png). As you can see width of col-6 is growing

Comment: Yes. But I just have noticed that your issue may be related to flex on your `body` element. Try to changing `flex-grow` `flex-shink` on this element

Comment: Triggering flex on body element makes its first child (wrapper) a flex element or not. Still that doesn't shed a light on why long text will enlarge .col-6 properly while explicit width: 250px property make it overflow col-6. Disable flex on body just make wrapper 100% width

Comment: To summarize: just long text enlarges .text element that enlarge .col-6 respectively. And explicit width: 250px enlarge .text element but wont enlarge .col-6. In "250px width case" it will be cut off by max-width: 50% property on col-6. But why oO

Answer (score 0):

This behavious is based on cycling width calcuations. I've narroved this case to simplier example. More here:
[Why inner flex width is overflowing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972828/why-inner-flex-width-is-overflowing#67973314)