# Why inner flex width is overflowing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

friends. Consider simple following example that appeared not so simple to me. I am probably missing something.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.width {
  /*    width: auto; */
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/antongrekov/pen/rNyQqbP)

`.wrapper` element has a `display: flex`, as well as `.box` element.

div with class width has an explicitly set **width to 190px;** which is more than its content width
still this div os overlaping its container

If you set **width to auto**, or remove **display: flex from .wrapper** div all is fine
Why ?

Comment: do you need a detailed explanation or a simple fix?

Comment: Explanation. I want to understand how width of .box -> div as well as .box container itself is calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erase the `max-width: 50%` setting from the last rule. It conflicts with the `width: 190px` setting for the `.width` class.

The conflict is that the `width` setting for the `.width` class is applied to the first flex item's *child* , not to that flex item itself, so the child is wider than the flex item is allowed to be by the `max-width: 50%` setting.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.width {
  /*    width: auto; */
  width: 190px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you apply the `width` setting directly to the first flex child, the situation is different, i.e. the 190px width won't be kept:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
}

.width {
  /*    width: auto; */
  width: 190px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know about max-width. but how width of .box > div is calculated if you keep max-width ? example markup is just as in bootstrap, this is where my question come from. html: .row(display: flex) > .col-6(max-width: 50%) + .col-6(max-width: 50%). Imagine there is an element inside with fixed width. You will get same overflow result

Comment: please note the addition to my answer (second paragraph)

Comment: I noted it, ty. max-width is not conflicting it rather take over width property, not allowing it to grow more than 50%. But 50% of what ? Of .box container and what is it width ? Calculated by its child ? One of its child is pure <div> with another div of 190px wide inside. This is what bothers me. Why won't make width of .box based on max-content as specification says and enlarge it rather than overflow

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's not a logical behaviour. I tried a few things just now, but I can't get a more satisfying result either. Although usually, flex containers do have a set width, since most of the time one of the main goals is to distribute the flex children across the whole width (or height) of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a complex calculation of the width due to a cyclic dependancy

To better understand, you need to compare before and after adding the `max-width`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin:5px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Two</div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice how in both cases, the blue rectangle (the `.box` element) has the same width that is based on the child width (150px + auto + auto).

What is happing here is that `max-width:50%` need a reference to be resolved and this reference is the `.box` element BUT the width of `.box` depend on its content (because it's a flex item) so we have a cylce. In this case, the browser will first ignore the max-width, will calculate the width of `.box` and later apply the `max-width:50%` considering the calculated width of `.box`.

Your first item is contributing with more than 50% of the total width that's why applying `max-width:50%` to it will make it shrink and you have your overflow (150px > 50% of (150px + auto + auto) )

If one of the other element were bigger you may not face an overflow because 150px will be smaller than 50%

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  margin:5px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two Two Two Two Two Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Two Two Two Two Two Two</div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If remove `display:flex` the issue will not occur because `.box` is no more a flex item and its width no more depend on its content. It has the a default full width:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin:5px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  width: 150px;
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Two</div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see `max-width:50%` is now bigger than your element width so no overflow.

Using `width:auto` you won't have the issue because auto for a block element mean take all the available width, so your item will shrink and the div inside will also shrink with it.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin:5px;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  background: green;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Two</div>
    <div style="max-width: 50%;">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example with your inner div resizable so you can play and see how it behave:

```css
.wrapper {
  margin:5px;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  background: green;
  width:300px;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width:50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will always have an overflow when `W > 50%*(W + auto)` where auto refer to  the auto width of the other elements.

Let's make `auto=0` by removing ther other divs

```css
.wrapper {
  margin:5px;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border:4px solid blue;
}

.width {
  background: green;
  width:300px;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width:50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <div class="width">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Always an overflow because `W > 50%*W` is always true!

Comment: Ty for such a detailed explanation. I've never thought before about cycling width calculations. Thats a very good knowledge to think of. I will come back later to your answer and over thought it, and mark as an answer.